# Adding newline in google form created using Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I am fetching contents from Spreadsheet and adding it as items in form through Google Apps script. When I have a text in multiple lines (texts with new line breaks) in a cell, upon generating the form, it appears in a single line. I need to have it as exactly as I am giving in the sheet. Is there any way to achieve this using Apps script?

Here is the code I used to copy data from Sheet to crate item in form:

```
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(mySheetURL);
     var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
     var cellRange = 'C2:C6'
     var ques = sheet.getRange(cellRange).getValues();
     var newForm = FormApp.openByUrl(myformURL);
     var QOD = newForm.addMultipleChoiceItem();
     QOD.setTitle(ques);
```

Content in my Spreadsheet Cell:

[image]

Content in form:

[image]

Comment: Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is  suggested in [ask].

Comment: Please share the code that your using to add the text to the form.  If you use a paragraph long answer and put in separate lines with a control enter, when the form loads them into the spreadsheet it preserves the line feeds.

Comment: I am using multipleChoice Item. And I am fetching data from Sheet to create a form items, not loading form data into the spreadsheet. @Cooper

Answer (score 0):

### Apps Script retrieves and passes the line break as intended from Sheets to Form

The only problem is how you retrieve the values:

- `cellRange[1][1]` is not a valid request, because a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) is a class, not a 2-D array.
- Opposed to it [`values`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) indeed returns you a grid and you can retrieve the grid elements by their indices.
  Mind that the indices start with [0], not with [1].
- Consequently `getRange(cellRange).getValues()[1][1]` would return you `null` because `cellRange = 'C2:C6'` contains only one column and it has the index [0].

**Correct request:**

```js
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(mySheetURL);
     var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
     var cellRange = 'C2:C6'
     var ques = sheet.getRange(cellRange).getValues()[0][0];
//also possible: var ques = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
     var newForm = FormApp.openByUrl(myformURL);
     var QOD = newForm.addMultipleChoiceItem();
     QOD.setTitle(ques);
```